# How can I set the Authorize attribute for Users to something from a dbcontext (i.e. Authorize(Users = dbcontext.Users...) in MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a controller where I would like to set up an attribute on an action in my controller to authorize users based on username (not role). The issue is that I don't want to manually type out the name of every person who is authorized to view the page. So, as an example, rather than doing:

```
[Authorize(Users="John,Mark,Henry")]
public ActionResult Test()
{
   ...
   ...
   ...
   return View();
}
```

I would like to do this:

```
[Authorize(Users=db.Users.Where(x => x.DepId = 3).Select(x => x.ADName).ToList())]
public ActionResult Test()
{
   ...
   ...
   ...
   return View();
}
```

I just can't seem to find any documentation out there on the best way to handle this. From what I've seen so far, it looks like I need to have some kind of constant set in the attribute line.

I have tried creating a static string and initializing it with the controller constructor using String.Join(",",list), but Visual Studio complains that the attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression, or array creation expression. So I send it a List, and it complains that it needs to be a string expression. Obviously I cannot set a constant to the output of a function, so that's out too.

I see plenty of articles online talking about creating custom role providers (which I am indeed using), but nothing about using a list inside for the authorize attribute.

I know I can use roles as well, but in this particularly case I want to authorize by user. What do I need to do to make this work?

Comment: you must be use roles and put your user in same role and user [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]

Comment: you must be use roles and put your user in same role and use [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]

Comment: Foadabd, thanks for the reply!  However, this will unfortunately not work. As I mentioned in my original post, I know I can use roles, but I want to authorize by user in this particular case.

Comment: ok you must create custom Authorize 
 check this link : https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/56fb14/custom-authorization-in-mvc/

Comment: Thanks again for replying! I have already created a custom role provider and a custom authorize class. While creating the custom authorize class will allow me to handle the data that gets passed into it, I don't see how I can send in a list of users to it in the first place without making it a constant string.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative idea...

You can create a middleware that performs the needed checks (you can also extend the logic even further there).

Trust me custom middlewares can be very powerful..

The middleware execution can be toggled using attributes (like [Authorize]) too.
This is how I made one that we use for Unauthorized login page redirection for auth0.

https://github.com/bobi591/auth0RedirectionMiddleware

More info how to implement:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-5.0
https://michaelscodingspot.com/attributes-and-middleware-in-asp-net-core/